# Can't transform a python program into exe

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I want to transform a simple .py code into .exe using PyInstaller, the program works fine with python, but when I transform it into .exe using PyInstaller, it returns the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named numpy.core._dtype.ctypes`

I tried installing the ctypes module, but the same error happenened.

How can I fix this error?

**.py code:**

```
import numpy
input("Worked")
```

**cmd output:**

```
C:\Users\enzo\Desktop\Compilando\dist\iaf>iaf.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iaf.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\enzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\P
yInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
  File "c:\users\enzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\P
yInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 369, in <module>
  File "site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 358, in _get_typecodes
  File "site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py", line 358, in <dictcomp>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._dtype_ctypes'
[2872] Failed to execute script iaf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after I added to the beginning of the code:

```
import numpy.core._dtype_ctypes
```

my code works

spied on KmolYuan

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can downgrade your numpy package via

```
python -m pip install numpy==1.15.0
```

as there seems to be a problem for pyinstaller using the current numpy release (1.16.0).